# Facing error while trying to use GKE managed certificates with K8s Gateway Resource

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

Is GKE ManagedCertificate resource supported with the gateway resource? If it supports how GKE Gateway support using the ManagedCertificate resource?

> Error :failed to translate Gateway "gateway/platform": Error GWCER105: Listener "platform" is invalid, err: You specified {Group: networking.gke.io, Kind: ManagedCertificate} in the certificate reference, {Group: , Kind: Secret} are the supported values.

I'm the new user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Restrictions and [limitations of Secure gateway](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/secure-gateway#restrictions_and_limitations)

The GKE Gateway does not support using the ManagedCertificate resource and hence you are facing this error.

But you can try below as a work around :

- Assuming you are utilizing external GatewayClass (for example gke-l7-gxlb), you can utilize certificates from [Certificate Manager](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/secure-gateway#secure-using-certificate-manager).
- Assuming you are using internal GatewayClass (for example gke-l7-rilb), you can utilize Google-managed SSL certificates, yet you'll have to [create a SSL Certificate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/secure-gateway#secure-using-ssl-certificate) asset instead of utilizing the ManagedCertificate asset.
- Refer to this [Github link](https://github.com/gke-demos/gateway-api/tree/main/wildcard) for some sample resource specs.

Comment: useful information